# how do I assign a class method as the callback for ACameraCaptureSession_captureCallbacks in c++ using android NDK

Tags: c++, android-ndk

I ran into a problem I don't understand in my c++ android ndk code. When using the camera there are a number of callbacks you give the camera2 api such as these defined in a ACameraCaptureSession_captureCallbacks structure. Today I was trying to put all my camera code into a class, but when it came time to assign the callback functions I couldn't figure out how to do it.  Right now I still have the callback functions as just external functions outside of the class.

So for the class:

```
ACameraCaptureSession_captureCallbacks captureCallbacks;


    DualCamera::DualCamera(){  
        captureCallbacks.context = this;
        captureCallbacks.onCaptureCompleted = onCaptureCompleted;
    }
```

Then for the function:

```
void onCaptureCompleted (
        void* context, ACameraCaptureSession* session,
        ACaptureRequest* request, const ACameraMetadata* result){

}
```

Defined like this it works fine, but if I try to bring onCaptureCompleted inside my class I can't figure out how to assign it to captureCallBacks.onCaptureCompleted.  I tried this.onCaptureCompleted, &DualCamera::onCaptureCompleted, casting to void * and a few others but I'm stuck. What's the right way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: What error message or problem did you run into when you tried these methods?

Comment: if I define onCaptureCompleted to be part of the class, then the compiler complains: "error: reference to non-static member function must be called"  If I try setting it like this onCaptureCompleted = DualCamera::onCaptureCompleted , then it complains "error: reference to non-static member function must be called".  Same error if I try this->onCaptureCompleted;